# Django haystack filter in search index

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-haystack, whoosh

I have a search working fine on my project. But in my models I have a boolean field named `is_active`.

I want the search occurs only when is_active is True, but I've been testing this without any satisfatory response.

my search_indexes.py:

```
    from haystack.indexes import *
    from haystack.sites import site
    from core.models import AnuncioSolucao

    class AnuncioSolucaoIndex(RealTimeSearchIndex):
        text = CharField(document=True,use_template=True)

    site.register(AnuncioSolucao,AnuncioSolucaoIndex)
```

That way it works, but also bring me all the `is_active == False`. Any thoughts?

Comment: what haystack version are you using ?

Comment: Haystack 1.2.7 and whoosh 2.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a method called read_queryset on the SearchIndex API. I just had to override this:

```
class AnuncioSolucaoIndex(RealTimeSearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True,use_template=True)
    def read_queryset(self):
        super(AnuncioSolucaoIndex,self).read_queryset()
        return AnuncioSolucao.objects.filter(is_active=True)
```